# Marking Component Class as Dependent Upon Another

Tags: c#, .net

My application has a "pipeline" concept that runs through and executes one to many "components".  Some of these components cannot be executed unless one to many other components are run before it.

My goal is to somehow annotate these dependencies so that I can test via unit tests that they are ordered properly for execution in the pipeline.

Is there a construct in C#/.NET that would support this objective?  My plan was to just inherit from a base component class that has a property on it, but I was hoping there'd be a better way.

Thoughts/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes would be one way to go:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx

Comment: Please don't use version-specific URLs unless the answer is specific to a version of .NET.

Comment: Marking as answer as this is the route I've gone!  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, if a "Component" requires other components to be exectuted as a pipeline, you should design your system so that it takes the other "components" as as argument to either it's constructor, or to its execution method.

This way, it's impossible to create or execute your component without having properly initialized data.

Comment: A 100% sound suggestion that I wholly agree with that's predictably impossible as it's a big, immovable behemoth of an application that I didn't write.  :)

Comment: @Adam: That stinks - You can't force the execution to occur within your components execute method, if it hasn't previously happened?

Comment: I can "force" it sure, but these "pipelines" that run the components could be created by anybody, and the components are reused.  Joe Shmoe may come along, not realize that Component X depends on Component Y happening first and break the app.  This mission of mine is to make it testable so a unit test can assure that there aren't going to be any [possibly runtime] errors caused by orders being off.

Comment: @Adam: Unfortunately, it's difficult to know what options you have, without seeing how your pipeline is implemented.  If you can walk the pipeline to check for the requirements, that's nicer.  Encapsulating all requirements directly is often the nicest, but that has other issues in terms of limiting reusability.

Comment: Sounds... similar... to what I'm trying to do.  I'm tagging the components that mark their dependencies, then I'll be walking through the components in each pipeline and assuring that their dependencies are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement yourself in C# the pattern [Chain Of Responsability](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternChain.aspx). All object contain the next step (like a linked list) and it executes one after the other.

[image]